# How to display changed date on material datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I have this calendar that i want to display the default value of user's previously input date.
However it does not display any value when I try to change the date. New date is still being able to save so I'm curious how to fix the displaying on data change.

Here is the code for reference

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Date of Birth: No change Display" [formControl]="getDate(userPrivate.date_of_birth)" [(ngModel)]="userPrivate.date_of_birth">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp >
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

and on my .ts

```
getDate(x){
  // convert Epoch time to formcontrol
  var date = new FormControl(new Date(parseInt(x)));
  // return newDate;
  return date;
  }
```

Comment: patch the form control, why are you using ngModel with formControl?

Comment: That is because I'm still fairly new to angular and trying out reactive form for the first time using the guide from https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview and added my own ngModel to get the data value. Will look into patchvalue

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done when I was working with mat-datepicker

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Choose a date" [formControl]="dateForm" (click)="dp.open()"
        (dateChange)="dateChange($event)" #dateInput>
    <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
```

In .ts, I'm using *moment* library to set the date to the formcontrol

```
this.dateForm.setValue(moment(previous_input_date, date_format));
```

Comment: That's a good tip.  In the above example, I'm using *event binding* on the (dateChange) event, as per the material documentation https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

Comment: Now that i looked in depth, you're perfectly right.